# jrebel web link not work

Tags: web, monitoring, jrebel

I'm using jrebel with an embedding jetty in a scala project, but it does not work very well.

First, I added the source directory and the web resource directory into the rebel.xml, then launched jetty, edited the scala file and compiled, jrebel detected the classes and worked perfect.

However, when I edited the web files such as html, css and js, it didn't work. No corresponding changes were found in the target directory.

So anyone knows the reason? Here is the content of my rebel.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<application xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.zeroturnaround.com/alderaan/rebel-2_0.xsd" xmlns="http://www.zeroturnaround.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <classpath>
        <dir name="F:\test\target\scala-2.11\classes"/>
    </classpath>
    <web>
        <link target="/">
            <dir name="F:\test\src\main\webapp"/>
        </link>
    </web>
</application>
```

Answer (score 2):

JRebel does not change the existing static web resource files in your deployed archive or build target directory.

The `<web>` element in the *rebel.xml* configuration basically tells JRebel from where to fetch static resource files.

For example in your case, if you'd do a HTTP request to `/css/mystyles.css` then JRebel will first try to find that resource from `F:\test\src\main\webapp\css\mystyles.css` according to the *rebel.xml* you've provided. If it can't find that resource from there, it falls back to the original deployed resource.

Comment: You mean that jrebel will not monitor the web resource files that I change in src even if I set a web link? But it printed "Directory 'F:\test\src\main\webapp' will be monitored for changes" when being launched, so what does this mean? That frustrated me much.

Comment: JRebel should pick up the changed resource in `/src/main/webapp` instead. You might need additional configuration if the servlet context path does not match with the actual directory structure in your `src/main/webapp` directory. For example, if you'd request an resource by making a HTTP request to `/foo/bar/html/index.html` and the actual resource in your project is located in `F:\test\src\main\webapp\html\index.html` then you'd have to change the `<web>` element to have an `<link>` element as follows: ```<link target="/foo/bar">
    <dir name="F:\test\src\main\webapp"/>
</link>```

Comment: Should you need further assistance with configuring this for your environment, reproduce the issue and send a description and a jrebel.log file to support at support@zeroturnaround.com